# On my iPhone XS Max, the Stack Exchange app doesn’t use the full screen

Tags: bug, ios-app

I think it did in previous updates, but something a few months ago undid that.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone11,6)
- OS Version: Version 12.4 (Build 16G77)